# iOS - Crash when app goes to background

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

We are massively registering a crash after the user closes the app and the comes back (even after several crahes):

http://crashes.to/s/2f9a6459d58

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
[NSNull boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f3f3d9d0

[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence addAnalyticTrackEvent:eventName:openedFromPush:messageId:fenceId:] (MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m:1674)

Any reason or way to avoid it?

Comment: What iOS SDK version are you using? Current version is 6.1.4. See https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/ for more info. If necessary, please open a support case.

Comment: We were using version 6.1.3. At this version you introduced PIID, which is a feature not present so far. PIID consumes a couple of properties we were not hydrating before: "etanalytics" & "pianalytics". The update catched up for surprise.

Comment: Have you opened an investigation for tracking this? The PIID value is optional and only used if you are using our Predictive Intelligence feature with attribution by something other than a Marketing Cloud contact key. However, regarding the crash, we'd want to look at a bit more data around your app and any other crashes being reported. If you can open a support request it will end up coming to our team fairly quickly.

Comment: Even though we have values for the properties "etanalytics" & "pianalytics", our app prod version was not using them. I guess the crash it's normal. However, I  consider such feature (PIID) should not be introduced in a hotfix bump (6.1.2 to 6.1.3). That's why it caught us up for surprise. So, we haven't opened an investigation ticket.